Python panda returned wrong data in a wrong column from the log file
I have below code for log data query and for some reason, it always returned the wrong value from the wrong column, anyone knows how to resolve this ?
audio_file_path = None
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(machine_folder):
    for file in files:
        if file == "AudioDeviceList.log":
            audio_file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            break
    if audio_file_path:
        break

if not audio_file_path or not os.path.exists(audio_file_path):
    print(f"AudioDeviceList.log not found in {machine_folder}")
    return {}

lines = read_file_with_autodetect(audio_file_path)
name_status = {}

for line in lines[3:]:
    if "------" in line:  # Skip separator lines
        continue
    parts = re.split(r'\s{2,}', line.strip())  # Split by two or more spaces
    if len(parts) < 2:
        continue
    name = parts[0].strip()
    status = parts[1].strip()

    if "Intel® Smart Sound Technology for Bluetooth® Audio" in name:
        name = "Intel® Smart Sound Technology for Bluetooth® Audio"
        
    elif "AMD-Dynamic Audio Noise Supression" in name:
        name = "AMD-Dynamic Audio Noise Supression"
    name_status[name] = status

You can see in the ouput data, thanks for any guidance here.

I have tried dump unwanted data as I just want to confirm the device status, however, the current code still display the unwanted data, the data source is like below,
Name                                               Status Manufacturer         Present

Speakers (Realtek(R) Audio)                        OK     Microsoft               True
Realtek Audio Effects Component                    OK     Realtek                 True
Realtek(R) Audio                                   OK     Realtek                 True
Realtek Audio Universal Service                    OK     Realtek                 True
Intel® Smart Sound Technology for Bluetooth® Audio OK     Intel(R) Corporation    True

if you print line (inside the elif statement) what does it print out? do you manipulate your dataframe anywhere else before you print it out?

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.
